# Any way to simplify the interface?

Tags: interface

As an aspiring game developer, but mainly a programmer, I don't really have the time nor the need to spend a few hundred hours getting cozy with all the features Blender has to offer.
So far I've spent about a total 20 hours trying to work with it, failing to make literally anything useful, and I dare blame my failures on the multitude of advanced menus and options within, amongst which it is nigh impossible to find the simple tools I'm looking for.
I am generally quite fine with the functional capabilities of say, SketchUp, as well as the simplicity of it's usage (although it's kind of bordering the minimum - wouldn't hurt to have just a few more options), however it doesn't play well with game engines such as Unity, and it lacks animation capabilities.
And as far as I've understood, Blender tries to appeal to a wider audience by giving people multiple ways of doing the same thing, depending on what you're used to, coming from some other software. This is nothing but a hindrance to me, as I am a blank page in this field, and the plethora of possibilities only puzzles me.

Alternatively, is there any other software to solve my amateur modelling and animation needs?

Comment: So basically you don't understand the software and simply blame it to the interface? You may give some more information about what you are actually trying to achieve in blender. The UI is highly customizable and u should be able to tune it to your needs. But be aware, blender is a very complex software that is heading more and more to a professional audience. Also people are dedicating years of their life to master the programm. If you "don't really have the time nor the need to spend a few hundred hours getting cozy with all the features" you should consider getting help from a professional.

Comment: Think of it as playing an instrument, you've got no idea what you're doing, but after messing around with it for the past couple of weeks, if not months, you begin to make wonderful things, magical things. ;)

Comment: Well, you are correct, Fate. I understand Blender is complex and mastery of it takes a long time, which is precisely the reason I'm wondering if there isn't something simpler for my wants and needs. I'm by no means asking to get the results of a professional without the effort. And I can't just "get help from a professional" - people's time costs.

Comment: BTW Blender works awesomely with Unity (google "games made with blender and unity" or see [this](https://www.blender.org/press/angry-birds-maker-rovio-plunder-pirates-featured-on-app-store/)...I know its not Unity but who doesn't know Rovio). Also Blender does NOT lack animation features...I think you need to spend a lot more than 20 hours in it to see what the developers have been working on for a decade!

Comment: Working awesome with Unity, totally agree. But I never said that it lacks animation features, that was about SketchUp, I think you misread. =)

Answer (score 7):

Tom, don't get me wrong here, but spending 20 hours in *any* advanced 3D modeling and rendering software is next to nothing. I myself spent way over 150 hours in 3dsmax years ago, until I got something that I was half-satisfied with. Then I spent additional +300 hours until I got a model that actually got sold.

Blender is no SketchUp. It has many more capabilities and nearly all of them are useful in some way to create game assets. You can close some of the areas of Blender's UI only to realize some minutes later, that you need them anyway.

So here's my answer based on my experience:

1. Blender's capabilities to simplify the UI are limited. Besides closing areas there is nothing I know that's easy to do and then also easy to undo.
2. If you are new to creating game assets and really want to get into it you sooner or later want to watch tutorials and it's incredibly hard to follow them if your UI looks different than the one you see in the screenshots or videos.
3. As an aspiring game developer you sooner or later will have to make the decision if you rather want to create game assets or rather be a programmer. (I myself started as a programmer by trade, then worked in Devops and IT Security).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to update my answer from years ago with a fresh new answer.

My fresh new answer is learn by doing.  The absolute best tutorial you can do is free and is on youtube.  Look it up. The tutorial is called "Blender Beginner Tutorial" by "Blender Guru".  In the tutorial you will learn how to make a donut.  You learn much more than just that, you also learn the interface because this tutorial is very indepth.  Give that a go.

=====

I feel your pain man. I know this question is a couple of years old, but i think a fresh answer might help others who have the same question.  I found your question when I googled how to simplify the blender interface.

I know the first time i opened blender, I saw a million buttons and coming from 3dsmax, lightwave, and alias wavefront a very long time ago, the right click to select was really confusing.

More recently i tried the v2.8.  You may want to try that out. They have made some adjustments to the interface that at least for me in the modelling area seems to be much better.  It is very easy to extrude faces and make neat shapes.

I do wish that there was a "beginner" mode or something to hide some of the more lesser used features.